# Trusted Checkins on foursquare

Tags: foursquare

David of the foursquare-support-Team directed me here to leave my question for answering here...

We are currently thinking about publishing our own venues on foursquare - about 1000 of them and more to come. We would love to offer a mayor special like "50% off the bill".

Getting the information, that the mayor just checked in: No problem here - already tried to implement that and it works.

But as we are going to give money away with our 50%-special, we absolutly need to be shure, that the person who checked in is certainly inside the venue.

The current fraud-detection does not work good enough for us - today I checked into one of our test-venues, when I was about 25km away. No good :(

Here is one solution I would love to see implemented at foursquare to solve our problem:

- If "trusted checkins" are enabled, the venue can still be visited by searching for it or using its URL. When checking in this way, you are awarded the regualr points, but you cannot gain any mayorship or badge (like when checking in via the mobile foursquare website).
- By using an API-call, a trusted-checkin-id is generated (for example venueid_token), that can be displayed to the user by a QR-Code, NFC-Tag, etc. When this special venue-id is opened, checkins are "trusted" and are rewarded with mayorships, etc.
- Upon calling the same function again, a new trusted-checkin-id is generated (venueid_newtoken). Using this new id to checkin, you get all the benefits. Using one of the old special-checkin-id, will *not* give you those perks.
- Of course, trusted-checkin-ids can only be generated by an account associated with the venues in question.

Using this - I think quite simple system - we could present our users QR-codes to checkin and be shure, they cannot cheat.

Additionally, the beauty of this soultion is, that it won't require any change in the mobile applications already deployed by foursquare. Everything can be done directly on the foursquare-servers.

I would love to hear from you girls and guys at foursquare-engeneering-hq.

Cheers,
Martin

Answer (score 2):

Users are able to check in to venues anywhere, but if they're physically far away the check-in won't count towards specials unlocks or the mayorship. So while your check-in "succeeded," it didn't actually contribute towards you unlocking the special in any way.

These check-ins also don't count towards the merchant statistics, so you can look at the merchant dashboard for the venue and confirm that the "far away" check-in was not counted.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But I actually also got a/the mayorship for the location with the mentioned 25km-away-checkin. As at this moment we hadn't any special on this venue, I cannot tell if I would have unlocked it - but as I said: I got a mayorship...

Comment: can you e-mail api@foursquare.com with details? (user id, venue Id, checkin id (if possible) etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is how Foursquare works. They allow to checkin from far away. There's currently no know way (at least for me) to avoid it. Could you please explain in more detail, what are these 1000 venues you're going to add and why do you need this 50% major-bonus for all of them?

The only way I could think off to do what you want is to create a custom application that would use FS api to post checkins, etc, but will have additional check based on location and some custom equivalent of mayorship. Basically that's what we've done to avoid fake checkins - additional location check inside of our app.